# Can't add linear gradient over img

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues adding a `linear-gradient` style to an `img`'s parent `div`. I've accomplished what I want by loading the image as the `div`'s background image, as opposed to as an `img`, but that requires more styling to render the same. Not sure if I'm missing something.

Here's my markup:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=Carousel%20Image&w=826&h=620" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=Carousel%20Image&w=826&h=620" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=Carousel%20Image&w=826&h=620" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=60&txt=Carousel%20Image&w=826&h=620" /></div>
</div>
```

Sass:

```
#owl-demo {
  .owl-item {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%, #191919 100%);
  }
}
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/vygGeP

Comment: Where is `class="center"` is defined in your markup? And `owl-item` for that matter.

Comment: @c-smile Sorry, it's dynamically added by the carousel plugin. I'll update the code to reflect the output

Comment: @MarioParra update your codepen to include jquery before the owl carousel plugin since it is dependant on jquery

Comment: @zgood Done. Thanks

Comment: opacity, mix-blend-mode or z-index might help  or a pseudo on top holding the gradient... basicly your image is on top of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set you `img` to `z-index: -1;` and it should work (don't forget to add `position: relative;` also).

Like this:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWjebd)

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks this saved me!